# Debug async method in VS 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, asynchronous

MS said i can debug async method in VS 2013
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/07/02/debugging-asynchronous-code-in-visual-studio-2013-tasks-window.aspx

but when i try debug async method, it cannot show local variable, everything show as CS$0$0001. I type variable name in Immediate Window and it said that variable does not exist.

[image]

If i convert my function synchronous, i can debug like normal.

[image]

edit:
This is not a decompiled code. my WebView inherit from CefSharp.ChroniumWebBrowser

Comment: Have you checked the Task pane?, HotKey according to my VS2013 is `Ctrl+^,K` or `View -> Task List`

Comment: Async debugging in VS 2013 does work, or every .NET developer in the planet would have noticed, The screenshot's variable names though  look like *decompiled code*. Is `WebView` your own code or did you step into some third-party library's code using a decompiler?

Comment: Or perhaps, you've added a reference to the runtime DLL of one of your own assemblies instead of a project reference? In this case the debugger will find the source code but there are no debug symbols that can help it to translate IL code to source code variable names

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I have only 1 project, all other dlls are from Nuget: CefSharp.Winforms, Json.net

Comment: @Serv: my Task pane show nothing.

Comment: Does switching to "Managed Compatibility Mode" help?
Debug>Options and Settings>Debugging>General>Use Managed Compatibility Mode